# Why float data type treats X/Y (Eg 5/9) and X.0/Y.0 (Eg 5.0/9.0) differently?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion

I was working on this code in C language and was unable to understand the reason for getting different answer for these two codes.

first writing values without decimal point

`float num2=(5/9);`

this gave me the output as the following:

```
0.000000
```

with decimal point

```
float num2=(5.0/9.0);
```

this gave me the output as the following:

```
0.555556
```

what is the working or theory behind this difference of answers?

Comment: because `5/9` is an integer division, providing an integer value `0` and then, this integer value is casted to a float `0.000000`

Comment: Thanks for answer sir but can you please let me know why is an integer division taking place when we are using the data type float ? any idea where and what i can read to know more about this? thank you

Comment: Strangely related to [this question posted a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817328/why-is-int-not-working-correctly-with-j-but-long-long-is-working-fine). It doesn't become a `float` until *after* the expression on the rhs is evaluated and the assignment is coming into play; that expression is purely `int` in `5/9`, which is zero per integer division rules. Only *then* will it be converted to `float`, and thus become `0.0`. Force it to float via  `5/9.f`, or `5.f/9` or other combinations therein.

Comment: That is insightful.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

5 and 9 both are integers. So, the result of `5/9` is `0`. Everything is done here at the integer level and then put into the float `num2` variable. For getting the actual real answer `0.555556` you need to have at least one of the numbers as a float or a real. `5.0/9` or `5/9.0` or type casting one of them, `(float)5/9` would also work.

The theory is, the numbers are sort of converted/upscaled to higher data type (forgot the proper terminology). Like in case of `5/9.0`, the `5` here is first converted to `5.0` and then the division operation done. So, `C` is not looking at the left hand side of the instruction while doing the right hand side operation.

Comment: Thanks,what should i read to know more about the way arithmetic for different data types work?

Comment: @MankritSingh: While not intended as a tutorial or teaching reference, the language specification is the best source - see the [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), sections 6.3.8.1 (Usual Arithmetic Conversions), 6.5.5 (Multiplicative operators), and 6.5.6 (Additive operators)

Answer (score 4):

C considers 5 and 9 as an integers, as they are. So it does the operation in integer level, that is 5/9 is indeed zero. Than, this result is assigned to the num2 variable.

Whe you write 5.0/9, than C sees that 5.0 is a floating point value, so it will do the operation in float, which will give you a different result, and this now this result will be assigned to your num2.

You can also write this

```
num2=(float)5/9; //or
num2=5/(float)9; //or
num2=5/9.0;
```

Either way, you promote one operand to float level, so the whole operation will happen on float level.

Comment: `5.0` and `9.0` have type `double`, not `float`. `5/9.0` is evaluated using `double` (or better), not `float`. In `num2=5/9.0`, the `double` result is converted to `float` for the assignment. In some circumstances, this will produce a different result than performing the calculation in `float` instead of `double`. Programmers should be sensitive to these specifics.

Answer (score 2):

C evaluates expressions from the “bottom” up.

At the top, the declaration `float num2=(5/9);` contains the expression `(5/9)`. That expression contains `5/9`. That expression uses the operator `/` on the operands `5` and `9`. These operands are at the bottom.

`5` and `9` are literals with type `int`. `5/9` is evaluated using `int` arithmetic. The result is an `int` value of zero. Then the parentheses are evaluated, so `(5/9)` is effectively `(0)`, and so it is zero. Then this zero is converted to `float` to be used to initialize `num2`.

Because expressions are evaluated from the bottom up, they are affected by the operands they use. They are not affected by the context they are in. The fact that an expression will eventually be assigned to a `float` does not cause it to be evaluated using `float`.